# json deserialization issue with h2 while testing

Tags: java, json, h2

I have the following hibernate entity

```
@Data
@Entity
@TypeDef(
        typeClass = JsonStringType.class,
        defaultForType = MetaData.class
)
public class DbEntity(){
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "meta_data", columnDefinition = "json")
    private MetaData metaData;
}
```

The MetaData class is as follows:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MetaData {
    private Long amount;
    private Date date;
}
```

The metadata field is stored as json in db. This works with mysql. But I'm writing tests using h2 and am not able to read values in field `metaData`.

Exception I'm getting is:

```
Exception: The given string value: "{\"amount\":100,\"date\":1593690610000}" cannot be transformed to Json object
..
..
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given string value: "{\"amount\":100,\"date\":1593690610000}" cannot be transformed to Json object
..
..
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `foo.bar.MetaData` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{\"amount\":100,\"date\":1593690610000}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"amount\":100,\"date\":1593690610000}""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I'm using `1.4.200` version of h2.

Most of the solutions mentioned for the problem are around h2 supporting json or jsonb. But my version of h2 supports json.

Also, if I remove `columnDefinition = "json"` from `@Column` of `metaData`, tests work as expected. But, in that case, mysql implementation doesn't work.

[This](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#json_type) h2 official page suggests to add `FORMAT JSON` in insert sql statement. But I'm not sure how to add it as I'm using hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a really good reason to use json columns, just change de `columnDefinition` attribute in `@Column`

```
@Column(name = "meta_data", columnDefinition = "text")
@Convert(converter = JsonConverter.class)
private MetaData metaData;
```

And define a custom converter:

```
@Converter
public static class JsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<MetaData, String> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MetaData metaData) {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(metaData);
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public MetaData convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        return mapper.readValue(s, MetaData.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem you had.
fixed it by using JsonType, it will work no matter what DB you are using.
in class level:

```
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonType.class)
```

in column i have:

```
@Type(type = "json")
@Column(columnDefinition = "json")
```

I am using `hibernate-types-55 2.16.2`